# Setting formulas dynamically using VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, user-defined-functions

The two left columns (A & B) are constantly updated, which add data to each row, I want to dynamically generate formulas for the third column which contains formulas using VBA. My idea is when a cell in a new row contains a text, then the column cell next to it (Cx) should apply for the formula.

For example

B2= 3

B1= 2

C2 = (=B2/B1-B1)

If B3 = 4 then C3 should apply the same formula, and this should be applied dynamically.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I see this is your first question.  Unfortunately, written as is, this is going to be difficult for others to answer.  Try editing it to include screenshots and be specific of exactly what you are trying to do and show the code you have written to do it and be very specific with what your expected result is and what result you are getting instead.  Thanks and best of luck.

Comment: Check [`Worksheet_Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am not overcomplicating this, but here's my try. It's a little longer, but I believe it should be quite error prone and that the performance should be nice.

The code below belongs to the worksheet's code (of the worksheet that will contain the data), **so not into a new module**. An example can be found here https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html
[image: Where the code belongs to]

I hope it works well for you :-)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


'target is the cell/range you work with
Dim cell As Range 'the cell is going to be a variable for a single cell,
                  'since if you were working with a range larger than one cell, then this code would crash
                  '(this applies to things like erasing a range of cells)

Dim rng_y As Range 'temporary range that will be filled with the formula
Dim rng_n As Range 'temporary range that will be cleared

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Target 'Loop through each cell in the range you work with
    If cell.Column < 3 And cell.Row > 1 Then 'this if makes sure you're not going to edit any fileds you don't want to
        If Range("A" & cell.Row).Value <> "" And Range("B" & cell.Row).Value <> "" Then 'make sure to add the formula only to rows that actually contain any data
            If rng_y Is Nothing Then
                Set rng_y = Range("C" & cell.Row) 'this is for the first time when the criteria is met
            Else
                Set rng_y = Union(rng_y, Range("C" & cell.Row)) 'for all the rest ocasions, just joining the already found cells with the new cell
            End If
        Else
            If rng_n Is Nothing Then
                Set rng_n = Range("C" & cell.Row)
            Else
                Set rng_n = Union(rng_n, Range("C" & cell.Row))
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not rng_y Is Nothing Then 'enter formula to cells with the right data
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events of the app, so the loop doens't run again for no reason
    rng_y.Value = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]-RC[-1]"
    Application.EnableEvents = True 're-enable events, so any future code runs correctly
End If

If Not rng_n Is Nothing Then 'remove formula from empty cells
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rng_n.Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, It works perfectly well. Thank you again

Comment: Great, I am happy to hear that! :) if that is the case, would you mark the answer as correct answer to your question please? :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow thank you! :)

Comment: Hey, I wanted to ask what changes could I make so that the code will work for more than just one cell (Example, If three or more rows are added at once)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. For me the code works fine with multiple lines at once (pasting and dragging), I intended it to work with multiple lines added at once. Would you please let me know what steps lead to the code not working properly? Thanks :)